# Programming at Network Layers 3 and 2

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking, network-programming

Taking Windows 7 as an example platform, I would like to understand how I would write an application program at the layer 3 (IP) layer. Take as a  simple illustrative example the case where I'd like to implement ping myself in C/C++. How would I go about doing this?

The problem, of course, is that when operating at the IP layer, instead of the TCP/UDP layer, there is no port number identifying the process (*my* process) for the IP layer to hand the packet off to. So, this obisouly can't be a traditional application layer program.

Instead, I think what I need to is write a level 3 hdnler that does what I want and register it with the OS to displace the existing IP layer implmentatio.

Is my thought correcy? If so, how would I implement it? If not, what is the corret approach?

Finally, I'd like to ask the exact same questions about layer 2 (Ethernet). How may I directly send amd receive Ethernet frames?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket

Comment: For layers below IP, this is the most popular option: http://www.winpcap.org/ or http://www.tcpdump.org/

Answer (score 1):

[winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html) is best for your neeeds. 
you can send / receive raw packet by windpcap api.
have a good luck.